# Finding probability with $|X|$

Tags: distributions, continuous-data

Question:

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable having density $f_X(x)$ given by
$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2}(\text{e}^{−|x|})$ , $-\infty < x < \infty$.
 Find $P(1 < |X| < 2)$.

Is it feasible if to separate the inequality to $P(|X|>1) = P(X>1)+P(X<-1)$ and $P(|X|<2) = P(-2 < X <2)$ to find the probability from there?

Comment: Why don't you get $P(1<X<2)+P(-1>X>-2)$ directly? The way you said is harder than this, in my opinion. Maybe, finding $P(|X|<1)$ instead of $P(|X|>1)$ would be better, because $P(1<|X|<2)=P(|X|<2)-P(|X|<1)$.

Comment: You can show $|X|$ has an exponential distribution by computing $P(|X| < x)$. From this it follows that $P(1 < |X| < 2) = e^{-1} - e^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as

$$P(2 \leq |X| \leq 3) = P(-3 \leq X \leq -2) + P(2 \leq X \leq 3)$$

You can then compute these using the specified density function

$$ P(-3 \leq X \leq -2) = \int_{-3}^{-2} \frac{1}{2} \exp(-|x|) dx = \int_{-3}^{-2} \frac{1}{2} \exp (x) dx$$

Similarly you can write

$$P(2 \leq X \leq 3) = \int_{2}^3 \frac{1}{2} \exp(-|x|)dx = \int_{2}^3 \frac{1}{2} \exp(-x)dx$$

Add the resulting definite integrals to get the probability.